# HHKB, remap tilde?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying HHKB and I think I can get used to the keyboard except the `tilde` button.

The button with `~` and `backtick`.

I often use `~` to go to home directory.
I mainly use `backtick` in stackoverflow posting to mark `variables`

Is there a way for me to map the key somehow so that I can feel comfortable with both HHKB and normal keyboard (such as macbook's)

Does anyone use HHKB at work and macbook at home or similar and get comfortable with the key layout difference? (especially the tilde key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene,

Use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). Once installed, search for HHKB.
The remappings available are:

Change backslash to `

Shift + ESC to ~

Command + ESC to `

Change ` to DEL

Change Shift+DEL to Pipe (|)

Change DEL to Backslash

Checkout the Documents tab on the website for information on how to add custom settings to the private.xml file. Use that if you don't find any of the prepared settings satisfactory.

I don't use Karabiner specifically to remap my HHKB since I've gotten used to it. Though I do use Karabiner with [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to remap my CapsLock to Control if used with other keys for the internal Macbook Pro keyboard. It's also mapped to Escape if pressed by itself.